# PHP PDO fetchAll only returning result on localhost

Tags: php, apache, pdo, localhost, fetchall

Ok I'm hoping someone can help me past this and I think it's gotta be something simple.  I'm building a website using Apache, PHP, and MySQL.  The code runs great on localhost, but not when I make a network connection (by IP).

**Specs**

- Windows 10
- Apache 2.4.58
- MySQL 8
- PHP 8.3

**Problem**

Quite simply, I'm executing a SQL statement and it returns a result using fetchAll. It works perfectly on localhost and returns the expected results.  Accessing the same site/page by IP address from another machine (Windows 11) and the query returns an empty result (which causes a subsequent error due to null values).

**Code**

The code where the database connection is established is in an object that extends PDO:

```
parent::__construct($this->getDSN(),$this->getConnector("user"),$this->getConnector("password"));
parent::setAttribute(parent::ATTR_ERRMODE,parent::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The code where the fetchAll happens:

```
public function fetchAll($style=\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    try {
        $result = ($this->_queryType === self::SQL_SELECT ? $this->_statement->fetchAll($style) : null);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        print "DEBUG::".$e->getMessage();
    }
    return (!empty($result) ? $result : null);
}
```

**Steps Taken:**

Apache log files show no apparent PDO relate errors. The access.log shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2024:13:44:06 -0500] "GET /beliefs.php HTTP/1.1" 200 25
nnn.nnn.nn.nn - - [02/Feb/2024:13:44:12 -0500] "GET /beliefs.php HTTP/1.1" 200 25
```

The DB connection appears to be intact and I traced the issue to a single line of code but as yet have no clue why it's behaving this way:

`$result = ($this->_queryType === self::SQL_SELECT ? $this->_statement->fetchAll($style) : null);`

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I dumped out the contents of all the variables/objects leading up to the execution of the fetchAll, including $this, just to make sure they all contained the values I thought they did. All them matched what I expected, with the exception of the $result array (which remains empty for non-localhost connections).

Also tested with my cell phone (Android) just to see if it was isolated to the Windows 11 laptop. No dice, same outcome as on the Windows 11.

Comment: Are you sure you're querying the same database server in both cases?

Comment: 100% certain.  The database connection string components are stored in a site-level config file. Accessing the site will always point to the singular config file.

Comment: Does it only affect `fetchAll()`, or also `fetch()`?

Comment: So it's the same server, only the client is different? That makes no sense, PHP doesn't care where the client is.

Comment: Correct, same server, different clients. I agree, it makes no sense to me either. My only other thought is if it's somehow related to Apache configs. That seems like a stretch, but at this point, I'll try anything. I've never encountered this issue before. It's gotta be something stupidly simple that I'm just overlooking.

Comment: Let me try switching to a fetch statement and see if I get a different outcome. I haven't tried that yet. 1-sec...

Comment: I doubt it will be any different. There must be a difference in the query. There's no way that PDO could be sensitive to whether the client is local or remote.

Comment: Try using a hard-coded query to prove that.

Comment: Switch to fetch and all it did was return FALSE, where before was returning an empty array. Just for my own piece of mind, I cleared all the logs and bounced Apache. Been staring at the code a while and starting to make silly mistakes.

Comment: Checking the hard-coded query now.

Comment: `fetchAll()` returning an empty array and `fetch()` returning FALSE are both normal results if the query doesn't return anything. You need to ensure that the query is the same and there's actually matching data in the DB.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere!! The hard-coded query got me results on both the server and cell phone.  That's a step in the right direction. I have 2 objects I use for performing all queries:  Database (extends PDO) and Query (has a PDOStatement property). That lets me keep all my DB access contained and consistent. Since the hard-code query works on localhost and client, it's gotta be something in the objects. Now to figure out what???

Comment: Thanks for everyone who pitched in on this, I'll post an update once I have the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the issue.

Bottom line, the URL is different between localhost and client because I was accessing via IP address. Consider that:

```
"www.mywebsite.com/about.php" != "123.234.25.101/about.php"
```

The design of my solution checks a database for a given page's content based on the URL of the page (left side of the equation above). Hence when I access it by IP, it finds no corresponding record in the DB. The solution works as designed, but testing it via IP address is a limitation in this situation.